# Automatically generated mapper creates null objects, which prevents mapper from actually mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I have the following model:

```
public class OrdersList {
  private List<Order> orders;
  private int pageNumber;
}

public class PaginatedResponse<T> {
  private List<T> elements;
  private Integer pageNumber;
}
```

And I need to map any given instantiation of `OrdersList` to a new `PaginatedResponse<Order>`. For that, I've built the following mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OrdersMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "elements", source = "orders")
  PaginatedResponse<Order> mapToPaginatedResponse(OrdersList ordersList);
}
```

Whose implementation (automatically generated) is the following:

```
public class OrdersMapperImpl implements OrdersMapper {
    @Override
    public PaginatedResponse<Order> mapToPaginatedResponse(OrdersList ordersList) {
        if ( ordersList == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PaginatedResponse<Order> paginatedResponse = new PaginatedResponse<Order>();

        if ( paginatedResponse.getElements() != null ) {
            List<Order> list = orderListToOrderList( ordersList.getOrders() );
            if ( list != null ) {
                paginatedResponse.getElements().addAll( list );
            }
        }

        return paginatedResponse;
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is the mapper is creating a new `PaginatedResponse<Order>` object, which causes its `elements` to be `null`, and thus not really mapping `orders` to `elements`.

And I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: I wonder would it be too opportunistic to define elements as: `private List<T> elements = new ArrayList<>();` In your public class PaginatedResponse<T>

Comment: How do you expect MapStruct to add elements to `PaginatedResponse<T>` if there is no setter? If you have an added then you have to explicitly tell MapStruct to use it.

Comment: @BorisKukec it is not in my hand to change `PaginatedResponse<T>`. It is a class contained in a library I must use...

Comment: @Filip you were completely right. That class does not contain setters, so mapping is impossible like that

Comment: There must be a way to pass the elements to the map either through constructor (you need to use 1.4 of MapStruct) or through adders by using `CollectionMappingStrategy#ADDER_PREFERRED`